# Calculate the json's value then show in html

Tags: json, ajax

I have a json array:

```
[{"value": "1"},{"value": "2"},{"value": "3"},{"value": "4"},{"value": "5"},{"value": "6"}]
```

My code is :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "120.58.243.11:8080/needCal/myJson.json", 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + value.value+ < /td>");
            items.push("<td id=''" + key + "''>" + total of values + < /td>"); 
            items.push("</tr>");
        });
    }
});
```

I want to calculate the values, how to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "120.58.243.11:8080/needCal/myJson.json", 
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
    var items = [];

    var totalOfValue = 0;
    $.each(data,function(key,value){  
        totalOfValue = totalOfValue + parseInt(value.value);
    });

    $.each(data,function(key,value){  
        items.push("<tr>");
        items.push("<td id='" +key+ "'>" + value.value+</td>");
        items.push("<td id='" +key+ "'>" + totalOfValue +</td>"); 
        items.push("</tr>");
    });
    }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use the `reduce` method:

Something like this:

```
var total = arr.reduce(function(t, v) {
    return t += Number(v.value);
}, 0);
```